# Adding new object array to a spesific id, but it creates a new row

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to push new objects to my products array. I found out that findOneAndUpdate() method works for the first time if the array is empty. When I do a save() method, it creates a seperate row with only the products. I've tried everythig to my knowledge without success.

My Schemas;

```
const ProdcutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    productDescription:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    pricePerUnit:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    productAmmount:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },

    /*productImagePath:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    }*/

});


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    products:[ProdcutSchema]
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Mongoose ran on POST method:

```
const newProduct = new  User({

            email: useremail,

            products:[{
                name :product_name,
                productDescription : product_Description,
                pricePerUnit : price_PerUnit,
                productAmmount : product_Ammount
            }]
        });

        newProduct.save((err)=>{
            if(err) console.log(err);

            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        });
```

Comment: i can't see a problem in your code, can you explain the problem more, and share the code that you tried with `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: User.findOneAndUpdate({                           //Update product
            products:[{
                name :product_name,
                productDescription : product_Description,
                pricePerUnit : price_PerUnit,
                productAmmount : product_Ammount
            }]
        }).then(()=>{
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
            req.flash('success_msg', 'New record');
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: Sorry about the fotmat.. the findoneandupdate works if there isnt a record yet. If I run this and no record has been set, it sets it nicely

Comment: so the problem is when you execute `findOneAndUpdate` it updates the document to the current array with single item correct?

Comment: No, when because I do not want to update. I want to insert a product array where email=email (in mysql logic lol)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i think you should use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.

Example:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(your_condition, {$push: {products: your_new_product}});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I realized I need to push the array yesterday. I'm still learning mongo and nodejs so I was thinking I wouldnt want to update it, just insert data (like in mysql)